# Forcing char to be unsigned char in Clang / Visual Studio / GCC

Tags: xcode, cocoa, char, clang, warnings

It looks like forcing char to be unsigned char works like this:

1) Clang -funsigned-char command line option.
2) GCC same
3) Visual Studio /J option

In XCode (i.e. Clang) trying to build a Cocoa application I did the following:
Project->Build Settings->Apple LLVM 5.1 Language->'char' Type Is Unsigned

Rebuilt all the schemes:

I still get "Assigning to 'const unsigned char *' from 'const char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign" compiler warnings.

I also tried adding -funsigned-char into the compiler flags to no avail.

I can't determine the needed Clang pragma to disable the warning message :( i.e. #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wsomething-message").  [It would be nice if future versions of Clang had warning numbers like Visual Studio eliminate the difficulty of tracking down the text.]

I'd settle for disabling the warning.

(I'm not interested in casting every operation.  In all instances, char is being used for strings or byte pointers, in neither case is any math being performed.  I just want to push the bytes around.)

[ #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-compare" doesn't seem to eliminate the warning either ...]

Comment: It appears the warning can be eliminated with -Wno-pointer-sign just like GCC although it is seems nearly impossible to find this documentation for Clang.

Comment: That fixed it for me in Xcode 10.